# YouTube iFrame API: onStateChange passes undefined data

Tags: youtube-api

This seems to be a recurring issue as there have been a number of similar posts on the YouTube API Google Group over the past couple of years. Using the YouTube iFrame API (only tried HTML5 not Flash) the onStateChange event fires correctly (and calls the specified handler), but the data property passed is undefined. I'm running OS X Mountain Lion and the error occurs using both Chrome (23.0.1271.64) and Safari (6.0.2).

Any thoughts on what the issue might be would be most appreciated.

Selected code snippets

```
myapplication.controllers.Player = function(containerId, videoId) {

    [...]

    this.player = new YT.Player(this.currentView_.playerContainer_, {
        videoId: videoId,
        playerVars: { 'showinfo': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0 },
        suggestedQuality: 'medium'
    });

    [...]

    goog.events.listen(this.player, 'onStateChange', this.onPlayerStateChange_, 
        false, this);

    [...]

};

myapplication.controllers.Player.prototype.onPlayerStateChange_ = function(e) {
  if (e.data == 1) {
    this.startTimer_(100);
  } else {
    this.stopTimer_();
  };
};
```

Comment: do you have some error message? it can help.

Comment: There's no error message. The issue is that the 'data' property of the event object passed by the event listener is undefined. According to the API reference it should correspond to an integer describing the the state of the player as follows: -1 (unstarted), 0 (ended), 1 (playing), 2 (paused), 3 (buffering), 5 (video cued).

Comment: when is the onStateChange being fired?

Comment: The 'onStateChange' event fires correctly when cueing, buffering, playing and pausing the video (I've not tried the 'ended' state). This triggers the specified function (in my case 'onPlayerStateChange_') passing an event object (in this case 'e'), but the 'data' property of this event (i.e. 'e.data') is for some reason undefined.

Comment: Could you pass along the output of console.log(JSON.stringify(e, '', 2)) when this happens? And providing a live example would be ideal—apologies if you previously did so on the Google Group.